# What is the missing step to simplify this equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

From this function:
$$
G(L)=\sum_{h=-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma_{h} L^{h}=\gamma_{0}+\sum_{h=1}^{\infty} \gamma_{h}\left(L^{h}+L^{-h}\right).
$$
With $h \geq 0,\;\, \gamma_{h}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j} \psi_{j+h}\;$ and $\;\gamma_{-h}=\gamma_{h},\;$ we know that
$$
\begin{aligned}
1)\ \  \ \ G(L) &=\sigma^{2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j}^{2}+\sum_{h=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j} \psi_{j+h}\left(L^{h}+L^{-h}\right)\right). \\
\end{aligned}
$$

But then from here, my textbook derives the next steps with no explanation as to how:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2)\ \  \ \ &=\sigma^{2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j} L^{j}\right)\left(\sum_{h=0}^{\infty} \psi_{h} L^{-h}\right) \\
3)\ \  \ \ &=\sigma^{2} \psi(L) \psi\left(L^{-1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

How do we get there? In particular from 1) to 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that to obtain a specific $L^h$, I can make it with any product of the form:

$$(\psi_j L^{-j})(\psi_{h+j}L^{h+j})=\psi_j\psi_{j+h}L^h$$

Likewise if I want to make $L^{-h}$:

$$(\psi_j L^{j})(\psi_{h+j}L^{-(h+j)})=\psi_j\psi_{j+h} L^{-h}$$

The product $(\sum_j\psi_j L^j)(\sum_i\psi_i L^{-i})$ will expand to make a sum of terms of the above two forms, and also terms of the form $\psi_jL^j\psi_jL^{-j}=\psi_j^2$, which explains the result. Try visualise all the possible ordered pairs in the expanded sum of multiplications.

This is very similar to a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).